# Download count module does not work for me

Tags: views

I installed the [Download Count](https://drupal.org/project/download_count) module for Drupal 6. The automatic views were normally generated by the module. One of these views is file_download with a page format. The view should generate statistics, but I find no statistics generated by the view. I opened the view and I found everything is normal, unless there is something I am not aware of.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your file field to use private file system instead of public.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean under configuration -> file system ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but I got the following warning messages.

Comment: Yes set it up there but you need to change each field that should be tracked to use private file system. In the setting for the content type.

Comment: Sorry, I got a problem in posting the Warning messages. I will try to to set it up in the content type. The warning message was:

Comment: warning: Missing argument 2 for filefield_view_access(), called in /home7/filefivf/public_html/bbc/modules/download_count/download_count.module on line 380 and defined in /home7/filefivf/public_html/bbc/modules/filefield/filefield.module on line 497.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a bug. Search the issue queue for the message you got. Maybe there is a patch.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set it up. I went to the Manage fields and I got the field (field_post_doc) which is an attachment file. I found nothing that has to be changed.

Comment: Good to tell you the block generated by the module does not produce such error. Many thanks Pontus.